# Can't see the cookies in react js that are sent from back end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt, frontend

My BackEnd code for sending a cookie in Node.js

```
res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: false, maxAge: 3*24*60*60*1000 })
```

I am getting the Cookie in POSTMAN :

[cookie recieved in post man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JseGM.png)

But when I am sending a post req. using react js, I am not getting any cookie in the front end

[post req. made in react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9aB3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing `{withCredentials: true}` in your post request? Otherwise, the browser won't set your cookie.

Comment: No, lemme try that. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can't be sent to different domains. https://blog.webf.zone/ultimate-guide-to-http-cookies-2aa3e083dbae